# Having some trouble making a custom UIActivityIndicatorView

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityindicatorview, uianimation

I am trying my hand at creating a custom activity indicator view programatically. The problem is that it never starts animating. Here is the code for the spinner.swift class:

```
import UIKit

class spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView {

var flag = Bool()

override init(frame: CGRect) {

    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.flag = true
    self.isHidden = false

 }

required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func startAnimating() {

    self.animate()

}

func animate()
{

    if flag == true
    {

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

            self.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.5, y: 1))

        }) { (success) in

            if success == true
            {

                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {

                    self.layer.setAffineTransform(CGAffineTransform.identity)

                    }, completion: { (success) in

                        if success == true
                        {

                            self.animate()

                        }

                })

            }

         }


      }

  }

override func stopAnimating() {
    self.flag = false

}

override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

    let path = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: rect)
    UIColor.cyan.setStroke()
    path.stroke()
    UIColor.red.setFill()
    path.fill()

  }

}
```

This is the code in viewDidLoad() where I've added the spinner:

```
    let aiv = spinner(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width/2-35, y: self.view.bounds.height/2-35, width: 70, height: 70))
    aiv.hidesWhenStopped = true
    self.view.addSubview(aiv)
    aiv.startAnimating()
    print(aiv.isAnimating)
    print(air)
```

I don't see a spinner at all, and get the following message in the console:

```
    false
    <spinner.spinner: 0x7f82b3e08240; baseClass = UIActivityIndicatorView; frame = (170 298.5; 35 70); transform = [0.5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]; hidden = YES; animations = { transform=<CABasicAnimation: 0x6080000364a0>; }; layer = <CALayer: 0x608000035120>>
```

According to the logs, the spinner is hidden, which means it never started animating.

It would be great if anyone could point out where I'm going wrong, and suggest a possible fix.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem appears because of the call:

`aiv.hidesWhenStopped = true`

And the property isAnimating returns false because you are overriding the animate method and not use the foundation one.

 You should set this property in your custom class when you are starting and stopping your custom animation.

 The same case is the hidesWhenStopped. This should be implemented by you in your class.

 I would also recommend to use UIView as a subclass with a UIActivityIndicator inside because if you want to start the ActivityIndicator the AffineTransformation could disrupt each other.

Comment: The hidesWhenStopped could be handeld with didSet of your flag property